# Objects are not valid as React child... but it IS an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

This function is returning the error:

"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

and I can't figure out why. It shouldn't be returning an object, it should be mapping over an array, right? At the top of the code I'm using a hook for setState like so:

```
const [expSymbolData, setExpSymbolData] = useState([])
```

I have a similar code that's working properly. Also, when an error like this happens, is there a way to see what object it's returning instead of React just saying "nope, use an array!"? It would help me troubleshoot.

```
const GetSymbol = async () => {
                                    const rezsymbol = await fetch("https://api.scryfall.com/sets/83491685-880d-41dd-a4af-47d2b3b17c10")
                                    const jsonsymbol = await rezsymbol.json()
                                    setExpSymbolData(jsonsymbol)
                                        {
                                            expSymbolData.map((expStuff) => {
                                                return(
                                                    <span>{expStuff.icon_svg_url}</span>
                                            )}
                                            )
                                        }
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

`useState` setter is not a synchronous action. values will be updated on next render so either you can use `useEffect` to render based on updated values or simply use the data returned by api

```js
const GetSymbol = async () => {
   const rezsymbol = await fetch("https://api.scryfall.com/sets/83491685-880d-41dd-a4af-47d2b3b17c10")
   const jsonsymbol = await rezsymbol.json()
   setExpSymbolData(jsonsymbol)
   return jsonsymbol.map((expStuff) => <span>{expStuff.icon_svg_url}</span>);
}


// Alternate
const GetSymbol = async () => {
   const rezsymbol = await fetch("https://api.scryfall.com/sets/83491685-880d-41dd-a4af-47d2b3b17c10")
   const jsonsymbol = await rezsymbol.json()
   setExpSymbolData(jsonsymbol)
 }

// add a useEffect hook

useEffect(() => {
  expSymbolData.map((expStuff) => <span>{expStuff.icon_svg_url}</span>);
}, [expSymbolData]);
```

In 2nd scenario, handle rending based on new logic

Comment: Still getting an error. This is nested inside another map because one of the json fields returns an api call to another json file, and THAT json file has the url to the image file I'll need (icon_svg_url). It's a mess and I'm not sure I can even explain it properly.